# How do I use a redirect uri to obtain an access token?

Tags: javascript, redirect, server, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API and I'm confused because when I use a redirect uri on js fiddle my program seems to work perfectly but then when I go back and host the same code on my local server with redirect uri "http://localhost:8888" the 'alert()' and 'console.log()' lines don't do anything. Why does it matter what uri I use? I thought that this was the just the address the user gets sent to after the authorization takes place. Does this affect where the access token can be used?

My code (test lines don't seem to work):

```
<title>Testy</title>
<link href="scripts/cached.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        margin: 1em;
    }

    img {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
</style>




<div class="container">
<h1>Displaying User Data</h1>
<p>Log in with your Spotify account and this demo will display information about you fetched using the Spotify Web API</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-login">Login</button>
<button class="btn btn-res" id="btn-res">Result</button>
</div>





<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
function login(callback) {
    var CLIENT_ID = '04270f76089b4a65a3eb749c0addb583';
    var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8888';
    function getLoginURL(scopes) {
        return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
          '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
          '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
          '&response_type=token' +
          '&show_dialog=true';
    }

    var url = getLoginURL([
        'user-library-read playlist-read-private user-follow-read'
    ]);

    var width = 450,
        height = 730,
        left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
        top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
            callback(hash.access_token);
        }
    }, false);

    var w = window.open(url,
                        'Spotify',
                        'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
                       );

}
function ridDuplicates(artists) { // returns final artists array
        artistsFresh = []; // will contain no duplicate artists
    artistsFresh.push(artists[0]); // first element can't be a duplicate
    for (var i = 1; i < artists.length; i++) {
            var j = i-1;
        var duplicateArt = false;
            while (j >= 0 && duplicateArt == false) {
             if (artistsFresh[j] == artists[i]) {
                duplicateArt = true;
           }
           j--;
        }
        if (!duplicateArt) {
                artistsFresh.push(artists[i]);
        }
    }
    return artistsFresh;
} 

var i = 0;
function getUserData(accessToken, i) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?limit=50&offset=' + i,
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });
}


   var loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');

var resButton = document.getElementById('btn-res');
var artists = [];
resButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(artists.length);
});

loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
login(function(accessToken) {
    loginButton.style.display = 'none';
    var arr = [getUserData(accessToken, i)];
    arr[0]
    .then(function(response) {
        for (var i = 50; i < response.total; i += 50) {
            arr.push(getUserData(accessToken, i));
        }
        Promise.all(arr).then(function(chunks) {
            var artists = [].concat.apply([], chunks.map(function(response)                    {
                return response.items.map(function(item) {
                    return item.track.album.artists[0].name;
                });
            }));
            //nothing works here!!
            //tests
            alert("WORKS");
            console.log("hello?");
            alert(artists.length);
            alert(artists[9]);
            var newArray = ridDuplicates(artists);
            alert(newArray.length);

        });
        // nothing happens here either
        alert("WORKS");
        console.log("hello");
    })

});

});
});

</script>
```

Then if I run this code in jsFiddle with the redirect uri as "http://jmperezperez.com/spotify-oauth-jsfiddle-proxy/" everything seems to work perfectly. Can someone explain this/ how to use redirect uris in conjunction with access tokens to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors when running this code?

Comment: @MichaelThelin no, I'm not getting any errors. It just takes me directly to http://localhost:8888 without executing the things I want it to. I'm wondering if it would work on a real  domain name that isn't my local server?

Comment: @MichaelThelin After the user gives access it just takes me to http://localhost:8888 without executing the things inside. So it's a loop because I'm already on localhost. Is there a simpler way to obtain an access token? After debugging through the code, it seems that the window.addEventListener("message", function(event){..}) method (which pulls the access token from the response URL i believe) is not working because nothing happens if I just throw an alert("test") in the first line. Also, on the jsFiddle example the window closes out but on mine it stays open and redirects inside this window

Comment: @MichaelThelin I can see the access token in the response url in the window after I agree to let the app access my spotify data. I guess I'm having trouble extracting and using it though